# what is the difference between @Inject(Injector) injector and injector?

Tags: angular

is there any significant difference between this 2 statement in the context of angular 4.3.4 classes or these are just 2 pattern of the same thing?

```
constructor(@Inject(Injector) private injector: Injector) {}
```

and

```
constructor(private injector: Injector)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first explicitly requests the argument be populated from the dependency injector. The second is just a constructor parameter. For it to be injected the class must be marked as `@Injectable` (or similar ie `@Component`)

Basically, the first is more verbose and is typically not used since the classes we use in Angular are usually already marked with the correct metadata.

Comment: so the second one is also fine and preferable in your opinion?

Comment: @pro.mean The second one is preferable, but make sure you are decorating the class otherwise it is not functionally the same

Comment: decorating means using `@Injectable` before the class definition starts, right?

Comment: @pro.mean Yes; or others like `@Component`, `@Directive` etc

Comment: but this ( 2nd style)  even works without  `@Injectable()` and did not throw/complaint any error.

Comment: @pro.mean It won't throw at compile time; it just won't inject at runtime

Comment: `@Injectable()` is only *really* required when the service itself depends on other services being injected via the constructor. Most of the time, it is added it to a service by convention.

Comment: @R.Richards Totally true; most services depend on some other services though (and we do it by convention regardless)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I am right there with you. I add it to all my services.

Answer (score -2):

Kindly read the documentation of the [inject function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject)

> The inject function wraps a function into an injectable function. The
>   inject() creates new instance of $injector per test, which is then
>   used for resolving references.

Comment: I read and did not get into simple words and btw this is in context of angular 4 and your link is based on angular 1.6.x. that's why asked

Comment: Agreed, this answer has nothing to do with the question